# Exandable table in Microsoft Word form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I'm creating a form in Microsoft Word that will be distributed to various people. One section on the form is a table where the user lists all the tests that he/she has taken and some relevant details about those tests. I don't know in advance how many tests a user has taken, although I can assume it is at least 1. I'd like to create a table that the user can add rows to for each test. Some of the columns will have form controls, one has a drop box, one has check boxes, one has a date picker. I'd like to be able to link these forms with Access once the user has completed them.

Is it possible to create a user expandable table that maintains the form controls in each column?

Comment: I know this is a bit off topic, but could you use Excel perhaps instead?  You can do this task fairly simply in Excel, creating a user form in Word would be a bit harder.

Comment: I'm not opposed to that, but how could I get the user to create a new row with the control forms already copied?

Comment: My general method is to make a master row in a hidden second sheet.  Whenever you user adds a new row (either by clicking a button or using some other control) you just copy the row from that master sheet and insert it below the row they just used.

Answer (score 0):

I am on a Linux machine right now so I can't test and debug code for you, but I have made tables in Word before where the size is decided at runtime (in fact, I did it from Excel, but that is off topic).  However, I can tell you the general form is:

expression.Add(BeforeRow)

where expression returns a rows object, such as

ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Add(5)

Please see microsoft documentation of dealing with

tables:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa212430%28v=office.11%29.aspx

and rows:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223081%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Also, from the VB editor in word, go to help and search "table object members," "row object members," etc.

If this hasn't been closed by tomorrow I will write something up.  I will admit, in my experience Word VBA is a bit more temperamental than Excel VBA.

Comment: Hey H H, did you get this to work?  Are there any errors when you try to run it?

Comment: I ended up going a different route, creating a C# application and exporting to an XML file. I would be interested to see if this works though, if I have time I'll be sure to look into it.